# How to let pre authentication GET requests without an API key(anonymous users) pass?

Tags: php, symfony, token, restful-authentication

Here's my security configuration:

```
security:
    firewalls:
      secured_area:
          pattern: ^/r
          stateless: true
          simple_preauth:
              authenticator: apikey_authenticator
```

Resources like `/r/companies/1` and `/r/news/2` need to be accessible by my [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) application without the need of an apikey to be sent along with the request for GET requests. For `POST`, `DELETE` and `PATCH` requests that deal with changing the state of the resource, an apikey must be sent along with the request, the user needs to be logged in thus and get the chance to log in when that’s not the case through a 403 status code.

Right now all requests for resources are triggering the pre authentication process and the problem is that I wasn’t able to configure it to let anonymous users pass. This is just a test, here's the code(based on the tutorial [How to Authenticate Users with API Keys](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html)):

```
class ApiKeyAuthenticator implements SimplePreAuthenticatorInterface, AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
protected $userProvider;
protected $httpUtils;

public function __construct(UserProviderInterface $userProvider, HttpUtils $httpUtils)
{
    $this->userProvider = $userProvider;
    $this->httpUtils = $httpUtils;
}

public function createToken(Request $request, $providerKey)
{
    $targetUrl = '/r/login/check';
    if ($this->httpUtils->checkRequestPath($request, $targetUrl)){

        if (!$request->query->has('email')) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException('Credentials not correct or not present');
        }
        if (!$request->query->has('password')) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException('Credentials not correct or not present');
        }
        if($request->query->get('email') === 'testemail' && $request->query->get('password') === 'testpassword'){
            $token = 12345;
        }

    }else{
        if (!$request->query->has('apikey')) {
            $token = '';
        }else{
            $token = $request->query->get('apikey');
        }
    }

    return new PreAuthenticatedToken( //what is the meaning of this class?
        'anon.',
        $token,
        $providerKey
    );
}

public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
{
    $apiKey = $token->getCredentials();
    $username = $this->userProvider->getUsernameForApiKey($apiKey);

    if (!$username) {
        throw new AuthenticationException("Apikey not found");
    }

    $user = $this->userProvider->loadUserByUsername($username);

    return new PreAuthenticatedToken(
        $user,
        $apiKey,
        $providerKey,
        $user->getRoles()
    );
}

public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
{
    $targetUrl = '/r/login/check';
    if ($this->httpUtils->checkRequestPath($request, $targetUrl)){
        $response = new Response();
        $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);
        $response->headers->set('apikey', '12345');
        return $response;
    }
}

public function supportsToken(TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    return $token instanceof PreAuthenticatedToken && $token->getProviderKey() === $providerKey;
}
}
```

Right now this code doesn’t work for GET requests without the `apikey` query parameter since for this situation `$token = ''`  and therefore no `$user` will be returned from `getUsernameForApiKey()`

How to handle this situation? I'd rather have GET requests for ^/r not entering the pre auth process(I don't know how to do that). But if they do, how can I let anonymous users pass it? Right now I keep getting a `A Token was not found in the SecurityContext. (500 Internal Server Error)`. The code is incomplete obviously, but that's because I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Using the class `AnonymousToken` inside `authenticateToken()` solved my problem. Although I still don't know if it's safe or the best way of achieving what I wanted.

```
$apiKey = $token->getCredentials();
if($apiKey == ''){
    //request without a token
    return new AnonymousToken('anon.','anonymous',array('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'));
}
```

Here is the [Symfony API reference for the AnonymousToken class](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/TokenInterface.html).